# How can I bind a command from my IntemsControl list to my main ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I bind a command from my IntemsControl list to my main ViewModel?

```
<Window x:Class="MemoryGame.MainWindow"
        ...
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <me:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF44494D">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameBoard.CardList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Card01" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="Black">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectCardCommand, ???????????}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        ...
```

SelectCardCommand is defined in my main window ViewModel. I already tryed to add RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window} but it doesn't work.

---- EDIT More information ----

In my DataContext ViewModel I have this :

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand<string> _selectCardCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> SelectCardCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectCardCommand;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _selectCardCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => DoSelectCardCommand(s));
        // GameBoard = new Board();
        // this.StartGame();
    }

    private void DoSelectCardCommand(string card)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use two methods

using `RelativeSource`

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCardCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                           CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

or using `ElementName`

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCardCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
                           CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

---

**EDIT**

after executing the code I realized the reason, as rectangle do not have any event named `Click` so it does not bind, however you can bind to `UIElement.MouseDown`

alternatively I came up with a different approach to solve your issue.

I modify the template a bit to use Button and templated the button as needed and also changed the ItemsPanelTemplate so it look more like a memory game

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameBoard.CardList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectCardCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                                       Height="100"
                                       Width="100"
                                       Margin="10,10,0,0"
                                       Stroke="Black">
                            </Rectangle>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

the command

```
    #region SelectCardCommand

    public RelayCommand<Card> SelectCardCommand { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectCardCommand = new RelayCommand<Card>((s) => DoSelectCardCommand(s));
        GameBoard = new Board();
        this.StartGame();
    }

    private void DoSelectCardCommand(Card card)
    {
        if (card != null)
            card.Upside = true;
    }
```

this will help you remove `int.Parse(card.Substring(4,2));` and other string manipulations too

Comment: This is working. My command is binded but my DoSomething method is not accessed now. Grrr XAML is good for designer but hell for developers that don't care about graphical interfaces. I think I prefer draw pixel by pixel. I prefer to use my logic than my memory.

Comment: where is `DoSomething`? could you post a big picture of what you are trying to achieve and where is the blocking issue? drawing pixels might not be necessary at all with WPF.

Comment: I can't see the actual issue, however instead of doing the select card command, you can perhaps use a selector and bind the `SelectedItem` property. it is bit difficult to analyse the issue from the code. is it possible for you to post a working sample of your code? may I have a look at the whole.

Comment: you may upload to any file sharing service and post the link here or in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll follow your modifications.